# Need to change GET mapping name on Swagger UI

Tags: spring-boot, rest, swagger, swagger-ui

I am working with Java Spring Boot Application.

My Current GET method in RestController is below .

[GetMapping on RestController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34GKm.png)

After launching my swagger looks like below

[Swgger UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukwxb.png)

Is there any way, i can still use "/v1/person" in Controller , but on swagger i only want to display "/person".

I don't want "/v1/person" on swagger

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, It is not possible to do that.

I think you are looking at it completely wrong. Swagger is meant to be like a contract that you expose to the client(who ever is calling your API). This should have details about what the endpoint is all about, how a client can call your endpoint, with what arguments and what the client can expect in return.

If you use /v1/person in your controller, that means it can only be called with url `http://......./v1/person`.

Now if you (somehow) display `/person` in Swagger, then the client cannot call your endpoint and the basic idea of Swagger is destroyed.

Hope its clear.

Comment: thanks for your response. My Only intention is to display "/person" on swagger only, behind the scene , i want "/v1/person" to be called only.